# Expand this code to check if HTML comment in head includes a string

Tags: jquery, html

The `<head>` contains:

```
<!-- Foo 1.2.3 by Author Bill -->
<!-- Foo 1.2.3 by Author Joe -->
```

I can only get this far with some code which may be wrong:

```
var hc = $('head')[0].childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < hc.length; i++) {

    console.log(hc);

if (hc[i].nodeType == 8) { // comments have a nodeType of 8

// need something here to get a value and verify that one of the comments includes "Bill"
}
}
```

Comment: I would thing just using a `RegExp` or `String.indexOf` on the `hc[i].nodeValue` would work - did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own take on the problem would be to create a simple function, coupled with the use of `contents()` to retrieve the child-nodes of a given element. The function:

```
function verifyComment(el, toFind) {
    return el.nodeType === 8 && el.nodeValue && el.
    nodeValue.indexOf(toFind) > -1;
}
```

And the use (note I've used an element other than the `head`, as JS Fiddle doesn't really/easily offer access to the `head` element of the document, but changing the selector should make it work for the `head` as well):

```
$('#fakeHead').contents().each(function(){
    console.log(verifyComment(this, 'Bill'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EJy2D/).

As an alternative you could, of course, extend the prototype of the `Comment` node:

```
Comment.prototype.hasContent = function (needle) {
    return this.nodeValue.indexOf(needle) > -1;
};

$('#fakeHead').contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType === 8 && this.hasContent('Bill')){
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EJy2D/1/).

References:

- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).
- [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue).

Comment: TIL a valuable lesson about jsFiddle. Thanks! Will try yours and the others now.

Comment: I see what you did there with "needle". ;^)

Comment: Chose to go with the extension of the `Comment` node approach. Thanks again! BTW, sometimes `this`returns the string while other times it returns a #comment object.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped, and you are, of course, very welcome. Could you reproduce situations in which `this` is a string, or `#comment`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work for you:

```
if (hc[i].nodeType == 8) { // comments have a nodeType of 8

    var val = hc[i].nodeValue;
    if(val.indexOf("Bill") != -1){ 
     //Add glorious code!
    }   
}
```

Comment: Tried that and the one below here. I'm missing something: http://jsfiddle.net/rowbuck/AAW5w/26/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
var hc = $('head')[0].childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < hc.length; i++) {
    if (hc[i].nodeType == 8) { // comments have a nodeType of 8
         if(hc[i].nodeValue.indexOf("Bill") != -1){ 
              alert(hc[i].nodeValue);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and the one above here. I'm missing something: http://jsfiddle.net/rowbuck/AAW5w/26/

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't put your comments in the head tag, instead it's in the body tag.

Comment: you must test it on a simple html page.

Comment: TIL a valuable lesson about jsFiddle. Thanks!  Will try yours and the others now.